# phabricator: nothing in blocking tasks or linked task views

Tags: phabricator

I installed phabricator, and I'm trying to link a parent task to a child.  From the defect, whenever I click on "merge duplicates in" or "Edit blocking tasks", I see a dialog with a filter, but the list of tasks is always empty.

I definitely have tasks that can/should be merged; is there something else I have to do to "allow" them to be merged?

Edit:  I figured out that it's only my user that has this issue.  Other users are fine.  Any one else seen this?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this, offhand. If you think it's a bug, please file it in the upstream and we'd be happy to help.

Note that "Assigned to Me" is the default filter, so if you have no tasks, the list will be blank. You can change it to "All Tasks" to widen search scope.

[image]

Comment: i think this answers the question, but i also wondered countless times who thought "assigned to me" would be a good default here.

Comment: I think it's the default everywhere for tasks, which makes sense say if you're editing your diff, but not for duplicates. We should make this better.